# Add instanace of ManyToManyField with a Django class based generic view

Tags: django-forms, django-class-based-views

Is it possible to use django class based generic views with a ManyToManyField relation?  For example adding an "Entry" to a "Category":

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField()
    slug            = models.CharField()
    description     = models.TextField()
    entry           = models.ManyToManyField(Entry,null=True,blank=True)


url(r'^category/(?P<pk>\d+)/add', CreateView.as_view(model=Entry?????),
```

Here I want to add a new Entry to an existing Category instance.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing views with models?

Comment: I'm asking if I can use a generic view to add an instance of this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3//ref/class-based-views/#createview) to create the Entry, and then add id to a category by overriding the `form_valid()` method.